# Formatting results of fetchAll()

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) on a sql statement to query my database I made and currently have print_r() as a means to see it. Print_r returns values such as

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Type] => Poison, Invicibility, Heals [First_Name] => Acton [Last_Name] => Mooney ) 
        [1] => Array ( [Type] => Telepathy, Mind-Control [First_Name] => Adam [Last_Name] => Warlock )
```

I'm trying to use a loop to put this information in a table to style to make it nice and tidy so for example I want to see:

```
         Type                          First_Name    Last_Name
Poison, Invicibility, Heals              Acton         Mooney
Telepathy, Mind-Control                  Adam          Warlock
```

However I am currently stuck on how to implement this. I know it involves some type of loop but the query is dynamic and can sometimes have more than 3 rows of information so its a little confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a while loop when reading the results, not using fetchAll();

```
$stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmnt->execute($aParams);
while($row = $stmnt->fetch()) {
    echo stuff here....
}
$stmnt = null;
```

---

Edit : based on clarification of problem "my issue with that is how do i know the column number and name because the way my query works is that it can query any table"

```
// Use fetchAll as you have
$aResults = $stmnt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

// Then, check you have results
$numResults = count($aResults);
if (count($numResults) > 0) {
    // Output the table header
    echo '<table><tr>';
    foreach ($aResults[0] as $fieldName=>$value) {
        echo '<th>' . htmlspecialchars($fieldName) . '</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    // Now output all the results
    foreach($aResults as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ($row as $fieldName=>$value) {
            echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($value) . '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    // Close the table
    echo '</table>';
} else {
    echo 'No results';
}
```

Comment: my issue with that is how do i know the column number and name because the way my query works is that it can query any table. is there a way to instruct the loop to maybe parse this information ?

Comment: You're welcome. Clearer question next time ;) <grin>

Answer (score 0):

Like This,

```
<?php 

$arr = array ( 0 => array ( 'Type' => 'Poison, Invicibility, Heals', 'First_Name' => 'Acton', 'Last_Name' => 'Mooney' ) ,
        1 => array ( 'Type' => 'Telepathy, Mind-Control', 'First_Name' => 'Adam', 'Last_Name' => 'Warlock' )) ;

echo "<table><tr><th>type</th><th>type</th><th>type</th></tr>";

foreach ($arr as $key=>$val) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$val['Type']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$val['First_Name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$val['Last_Name']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}        
echo "</table>";
```